# NameError: undefined local variable or method `request' for main:Object

Tags: sinatra, rack, rails-geocoder

I'm building a Sinatra app which will take a visitor's IP address and return the weather of that location. Following the Geocoder [doc](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/), it would seem that getting the IP is as simple as

```
city = request.location.city
```

Entering that into irb, however, just gives the NameError you see in the post title. Going what seems to me the logical route and attempting to create a new class upon which to use the `request` method results in another NameError - this time for the `env` hash taken by `Rack::Request.new(env)`.

I can figure out how to build the thing on my own, but I'm stumped on this particular point, and assume that I am overlooking something not mentioned in the docs. What am I doing wrong that is causing `request` and `env` to remain undefined, and how do I go about correctly defining them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as simple as that:

```
require "sinatra"
require "geocoder"

get "/" do
    p request.location.city
    "works"
end
```

Your problem is that you trying to run it in `irb` where you haven't the context of a request which creates and populates your request object. To play with it I would recommend just to run sinatra. Or use something like [racksh](https://github.com/sickill/racksh), [tux](https://github.com/cldwalker/tux) which gives you a something like irb but with all the context needed.